# Автоматическое обновление SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Создал приложение для тестирования. Вопросы тестов хранятся в SQLite. Когда добавляю новый вопрос, то нужно удалить и заново установить приложение, чтобы появились новые вопросы.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы при обновлении приложения новые вопросы добавились автоматически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в вашем приложении данные (вопросы) не берутся с сервера, а находятся в самом приложении, то используйте метод `onUpgrade`, чтобы автоматически обновлять содержимое БД при загрузке новой версии вашего приложения. В самом методе пропишите логику, где старая таблица с вопросами будет удаляться и на ее место будет загружаться новая таблица, либо будут просто загружаться новые вопросы, если структура таблицы не изменилась.

Если используете сервер, то там все строится на взаимодействии вашего клиента и API сервера. Можно обновлять данные в БД через отдельные запросы к серверу (новые данные просто добавляются в таблицу, а если меняется ее структура, то используем все тот же `onUpgrade`).

Comment: Вопросы берутся из самой программы. Прописано метод ниже, но не работает.

Comment: Вот метод.  @Override     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {         //OnUpgrade is called when ever we upgrade or increment our database version no         sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);         onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);     }

Comment: приведите в теле вопроса полный код onUpgrade. так навскидку сложно сказать в чем может быть загвоздка.

Comment: Вот тут вес код посмотрите пожалуйсте и скажите. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3zV52Ts787pN1ZnZFRIdllDVUU

Comment: попробуйте сделать тест с принудительным вызовом onUpgrade и посмотрите что он выводит в лог.